# WordPress: Save Checkboxes in User Profile page and retrive in public page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In my WordPress, I have the below custom Checkboxes created for Users to choose their preferences.

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'extended_profile');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'extended_profile');

function extended_profile($user) {

<td> 
            <fieldset>
                <?php $data = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'services[]', true); ?>
                <label for="advisory"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="advisory" value="advisory" <?php
                    if ($data == 'advisory') {
                        echo 'checked';
                    }
                    ?>>Advisory</label><br>
                <label for="consulting"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="consulting" value="consulting" <?php
                    if ('consulting' == esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('services[]', $user->ID))) {
                        echo 'checked="checked"';
                    }
                    ?>>Consulting</label><br>
                <label for="training"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="training" value="training" <?php
                    if ('training' == esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('services[]', $user->ID))) {
                        echo 'checked="checked"';
                    }
                    ?>>Training</label>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
```

Saving the data:

```
add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_extended_profile');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extended_profile');

function save_extended_profile($user_id) {

    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

   update_user_meta($user_id, 'services', $_POST['services']);
}
```

In the `wp_usermeta` checkboxes array data is being stored.
However, below are the two challenges:
1) Selected checkboxes are not showing checked in the Profile page
2) With below code, not able to print all the checkbox options selected in the public page:

```
  $auth = = $post->post_author;
  $str = get_user_meta('services', $auth, true);
                        foreach ($str as $st) {
                            echo $st;
                        }
```

Need help in correcting this code and achieve above two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the thing that you are doing wrong here is that you treat `$_POST['services']` as a string while it's actually an array.

Any input that has [] in it's name submits an array, therefore `name="services[]"` is an array.

Also, drop the square brackets when you query user meta.

Try the following code in the extended_profile function:

```
<td> 
            <fieldset>
                <?php $data = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'services', true); ?>
                <label for="advisory"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="advisory" value="advisory" <?php
                    if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
                      if (in_array('advisory', $data)) {
                          echo 'checked';
                      }
                    ?>>Advisory</label><br>
                <label for="consulting"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="consulting" value="consulting" <?php
                    if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
                      if (in_array('consulting', $data) ) {
                          echo 'checked="checked"';
                      }
                    ?>>Consulting</label><br>
                <label for="training"><input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="training" value="training" <?php
                    if(!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data))
                      if (in_array('training', $data)) {
                          echo 'checked="checked"';
                      }
                    ?>>Training</label>
            </fieldset>
</td>
```

To list the option you swapped user id with the meta key:

```
$auth_id = $post->post_author;
$services = get_user_meta($auth_id, 'services', true);
foreach ($services as $st) {
    echo $st;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the Metaboxes checked in the Profile page. Any help in listing the array of metabox choices in the public page?

Comment: `if (in_array('advisory', $data)) {` was getting error `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given` if none of the checkboxes are selected. Have modified to check if not empty & no errors `if (!empty($data) && !is_wp_error($data)) {if (in_array('advisory', $data)) {`

Comment: @theKing Great, I've modified the answer so that others can check the correct one.